# Images not rendering in Visual Studio Code Extension Details whilst behind a corporate network

Tags: visual-studio-code

Images not rendering in Extension Details.
I am behind a corporate network which I assume might have something to do with the problem. No idea how to resolve it though.

See below for an example, where images have not rendered instead just show the image placeholder with the alt text for the image

[image]

I am running version 1.14.2 on a Windows 7 machine

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with security update as mentioned in the 1.14 release notes (Help > Release Notes):

> Extension Authoring
>   Constraints for rendering SVG images
>   Due to security concerns, we don't want to render user provided SVG images within VS Code. We added constraints for extensions to make it safer for users when they browse the extension Marketplace within VS Code:
>
> The icon provided in package.json may not be an SVG.
>
> The badges provided in the package.json may not be SVGs unless they are from approved badge providers.
>
> Image URLs in README.md and CHANGELOG.md need to resolve to https URLs.
>   Images in README.md and CHANGELOG.md may not be SVGs unless they are from approved badge providers.
>
> Images in README.md and CHANGELOG.md may not use data URIs.
>
> To help you adopt these constraints, VS Code shows linting errors in your extension's package.json, README.md, and CHANGELOG.md files if they are not yet compliant. Also, the vsce publishing tool performs compliance checks and prevents you from uploading a new version of your extensions if there are problems.

I'm running v1.14.2 on OSX and I had a quick look at the Beautify extension on my machine and can replicate images not displaying. The offending images are delivered over `http` which is not allowed in the README.md now, as per the release notes.

Some google led me to this [github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29979) where it was mentioned. :)

Comment: Don't think it's because the url is delivered over `http` as the first Example image in the image I posted to actually goes to a image file delivered over `https`. Also note this issue only happens when I'm at work. The extension details appear fine when I use visual studio on my home PC.